# Refreshing list on a page using html form and ajax

Tags: html, ajax, forms, textbox

The page has a `textbox` and a `submit` button. The textbox accepts an item. On adding an item, the list on the page should refresh and display new items using ajax.

The previous items should remain.

the code i've written so far: 
1) 123.html:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>PHP using AJAX</title>
<script type="text/javascript">

var time_variable;

function getXMLObject()  //XML OBJECT
{
   var xmlHttp = false;
   try {
     xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP")  // For Old Microsoft Browsers
   }
   catch (e) {
     try {
       xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")  // For Microsoft IE 6.0+
     }
     catch (e2) {
       xmlHttp = false   // No Browser accepts the XMLHTTP Object then false
     }
   }
   if (!xmlHttp && typeof XMLHttpRequest != 'undefined') {
     xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();        //For Mozilla, Opera Browsers
   }
   return xmlHttp;  // Mandatory Statement returning the ajax object created
}

var xmlhttp = new getXMLObject();   //xmlhttp holds the ajax object

function ajaxFunction() {
  var getdate = new Date();  //Used to prevent caching during ajax call
  if(xmlhttp) {
    var txtname = document.getElementById("txtname");
    xmlhttp.open("POST","321.php",true); //calling 321.php using POST method
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange  = handleServerResponse;
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xmlhttp.send("txtname=" + txtname.value); //Posting txtname to PHP File
  }
}

function handleServerResponse() {
   if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
     if(xmlhttp.status == 200) {
       document.getElementById("message").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText; //Update the HTML Form element 
     }
     else {
        alert("Error during AJAX call. Please try again");
     }
   }
}
</script>
<body>
<form name="myForm">
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>Enter Name</td>
  <td><input type="text" name="txtname" id="txtname" /></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td colspan="2"><input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="ajaxFunction();" /></td>
 </tr>
</table>
<div id="message" name="message"></div>
</form>
</body>
</head>
</html>
```

2)321.php

```
<?php

$a = $_POST["txtname"];

echo ".$a.";
?>
```

I am able to get output list of items(what i enter in textbox) on the same page without refreshing. 
wanted to know how i could add to the list keeping the previous items intact. i.e. update list keeping previous output
thanks.

Comment: What have you got so far? You really need to show some HTML and JS for us to be able to help you.

Comment: Try writing some yourself. See what you come up with. You seem to have a good idea what needs to happen. We're not here to write it for you, just to help you trouble shoot.

Comment: the code is working fine for displaying items on the page without refreshing. just wanted to know what changes i need to make to php (or js) if i want to preserve the output of previous items and add to the list on each further update.

Answer (score 0):

DO you wish to write us the code ?

You can get some samples here

http://sillythingsthatmatter.com/ajax/ajax3.php